# Post hoc test for Fisher Exact on 4x4 table

Tags: r, statistics

I have used the tbl_summary function from the gtsummary package in R to make a table stratified by 4 groups which includes a categorical variable with 4 levels. The added p-value from the fisher exact test come out significant.

How can I perform a post hoc test when the table for the Fisher exact test is 4x4?

So far I've only managed to find solutions for 2xc or 2xr tables

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.